# AttributeError type object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to open and print data from this JSON file using this code in my view:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
import json

class OnlicarView():
    import json
    from pprint import pprint

    with open('C:/Python34/Scripts/onlicar/mytest/onlicar/static/json/vehicles.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    pprint(data)
```

Here is my app url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from onlicar import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^onlicar/$', views.OnlicarView.as_view(), name='onlicar_signup'
       )
]
```

Here is my root url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^onlicar/', include('onlicar.urls'))
```

I am having trouble with the app url. I am getting an error saying that there is an Attribute Error and I don't know how to fix it.

Because I am getting the data from a JSON file there is nothing in my models at the moment. Am I meant to have something in the models?

My JSON file is printing now, but how do I render it to HTML instead?

Here is the error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.
 at 0x03F9C4B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autore
", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
mands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
e.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
e.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\
y.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\
", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\
", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functi
", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolve
 line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_m
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functi
", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolve
 line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109,
ort_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlo
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_re
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\mytest\mytest\urls.py", line 21, in <

    url(r'^onlicar/', include('onlicar.urls'))
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__
py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109,
ort_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlo
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_re
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\onlicar\mytest\onlicar\urls.py", line 5, in <

    url(r'^onlicar/$', views.OnlicarView.as_view(), name='onlicar_signup'
AttributeError: type object 'OnlicarView' has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Comment: can u show the full error..??

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with this code.

Firstly, you have declared this as a class, and used it in the URL as if it were a class-based view, but you do not inherit from any actual view class.

Just as seriously, in a class you do not put code at the class level; it needs to go inside a method.

Also, `pprint` will only print to the console, it will not display anything in the user's browser; you need to create a response and return that.

Comment: How do I display it to the browser please?

Comment: That's too broad a question to answer. First go back and read the documentation on how to write views, and fix the problems I have mentioned.